# Adding a new object to the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

This function changes my array by adding a new object to it (a new object is passed in the second argument). What method can I use to return a new array, and not change the old array?

```
const arr = [
   {  
     "name":"BMW",
     "price":"55 000",
     "country":"Germany",
     "certificate":"yes"
  },
  {  
    "name":"Mitsubishi",
    "price":"93 000", 
    "constructor":"Bar John",
    "door":"3",
    "country":"Japan",
  },
  {  
    "name":"TOYOTA", 
    "price":"48 000", 
    "max_people":"7",
    "country":"Japan",
    "certificate":"yes"
  },
  {  
    "name":"Volkswagen",
    "price":"36 000", 
    "constructor":"Pier Sun",
    "country":"Germany",
    "certificate":"no"
  },
 ];
function pushArr (arr, item){
    arr.push(item); 
}

let Cars = pushArr(arr,{  
  "name":"Audi",
  "price":"89 000", 
  "constructor":"Hubert Trumpius",
  "country":"Germany",
  "certificate":"yes"
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Use `Array.map()`.

Comment: SO is strictly non-political, so could you please change "Adolf Trump" to something less ... political (unless there is a german constructor that really has that name, if so, I feel sorry for him)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because JavaScript objects (which includes arrays) are passed by reference while scalar values are passed by value.

So when you pass in objects to functions and mutate them directly you are actually referencing the same object in memory.

To avoid accidentally mutating your object, you will have to create a new instance of the object before performing operations on it. There are multiple ways to accomplish this:

- [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)/[spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) you parameter `function({...f}, t)`
- Using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- Assign `f` in your function to a [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `f` (`f = {...f};`)

```js
const arr = [{
    "name": "BMW",
    "price": "55 000",
    "country": "Germany",
    "certificate": "yes"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mitsubishi",
    "price": "93 000",
    "constructor": "Bar John",
    "door": "3",
    "country": "Japan",
  },
  {
    "name": "TOYOTA",
    "price": "48 000",
    "max_people": "7",
    "country": "Japan",
    "certificate": "yes"
  },
  {
    "name": "Volkswagen",
    "price": "36 000",
    "constructor": "Pier Sun",
    "country": "Germany",
    "certificate": "no"
  },
];

//destructure your argument here 
function pushArr([...arr], item) {
  return [arr, item];
}

let Cars = pushArr(arr, {
  "name": "Audi",
  "price": "89 000",
  "constructor": "Adolf Trump",
  "country": "Germany",
  "certificate": "yes"
});

console.log(arr);
console.log(Cars);
```

It is worth noting that re-assigning your object will not update the value. Please take a look into [Call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) or [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
function pushArr(arr, item) {
  return arr.concat(item); // or return [...arr, item]
}

const arr = [{"name":"BMW","price":"55 000","country":"Germany","certificate":"yes"},{"name":"Mitsubishi","price":"93 000","constructor":"Bar John","door":"3","country":"Japan"},{"name":"TOYOTA","price":"48 000","max_people":"7","country":"Japan","certificate":"yes"},{"name":"Volkswagen","price":"36 000","constructor":"Pier Sun","country":"Germany","certificate":"no"}];

let Cars = pushArr(arr, {
  "name": "Audi",
  "price": "89 000",
  "constructor": "Adolf Trump",
  "country": "Germany",
  "certificate": "yes"
});

console.log(arr === Cars);
console.log(Cars);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for creating a copy.

```
function pushArr(arr, item) {
    let copy = arr.slice();
    copy.push(item);
    return copy;
}
```